# Let $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ be bounded sequences of nonnegative numbers. Prove $\lim \sup{s_n,t_n}$ $\leq$ $(\lim \sup{s_n})(\lim \sup{t_n})$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ be bounded sequences of nonnegative numbers. Prove $\lim \sup{s_n,t_n}$ $\leq$ $(\lim \sup{s_n})(\lim \sup{t_n})$?

Can someone help explain this proof to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N_s,N_t \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $s_n < \limsup s_n + \epsilon$ for all $n \geqslant N_s$ and $t_n < \limsup t_n + \epsilon$ for all $n \geqslant N_t$.  Then what can you say about $s_nt_n$?